# Unable to load dynamic library 'newrelic.so'

Tags: php, linux, drupal-7, drush

While running 'drush status' in other directory, it shows following error message.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'newrelic.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/newrelic.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/newrelic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/newrelic.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/newrelic.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'newrelic.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/newrelic.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/newrelic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/newrelic.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/newrelic.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Settings file missing: /var/www/html/tra/docroot/sites/com/settings.local.phpDrush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

I tried by modifying `settings.php` to `settings.local.php` which is present in `/var/www/html/tra/docroot/sites/com/` . 'drush status' command started working but website went down.

In my case, drush is working in `/docroot` and `/sites` but not in `/com`.

Answer (score 0):

On all my installations, Drush only works from the directory in which Drupal is installed and up. But if that was your problem, then you'd probably be seeing the '*you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment*' error.

That said, it sounds like you newrelic install is broken, so at least for now, comment out from your php.ini `extension=newrelic.so` and restart your web server.

For more specific instructions on where to do that, please tell us what version PHP you're using and in what environment (OS with version, any control panels like Plesk or cPanel?)

Comment: is this an answer or query/comment to ask more info?